# How to check if a dictionary contains a list with a dictionary inside?

Tags: python

I am wondering how I would go about doing a validation check to see if a dictionary contains a list with another dictionary inside the list? Here is my dictionary that I need to validate: {'custom_orders': [{'190': 3}, {'191': 2}]}

Comment: Is there a specific dictionary key you want to check, or just any value is a list containing a dictionary. Do all the elements in the list have to be dictionaries?

Comment: Please show what you tried and explain the problem it has. We're not going to write your code for you, but we'll help you fix your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to check if a list contains dictionaries and nothing else you can try this:

```
list_to_test = [{'190': 3}, {'191': 2}]
all((map(lambda e: isinstance(e, dict), list_to_test)))
```

Comment: `all(isinstance(e, dict) for e in list_to_test)` is shorter

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments above you can use [**`any`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) and [**`isinstance`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
d = {'custom_orders': [{'190': 3}, {'191': 2}]}

contains = any(isinstance(element, dict)
               for value in d.values()
               for element in value
               if isinstance(value, list))
```